# Get query's result as a single row?

Tags: mysql

Here's the structure of the table I get result from:

`id | reference_field     | value                     |
------------------------------------------------------`
`4  | product_name        | name of the product       |`
`4  | product_description | description of the product|`
`...`

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT 
 CASE 
WHEN reference_field = "product_name" THEN value 
END AS product_name, 
CASE 
 WHEN reference_field = "product_description" THEN value 
END AS product_description 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id=4`
```

and I end up with:
`product_name        | product_description       |
-------------------------------------------------`
`name of the product | NULL                      |`
`NULL                | description of the product|`

but what I'd like to get is:
`product_name        | product_description       |
-------------------------------------------------`
`name of the product | description of the product|`

Is it possible and what should I modify in my query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAX for this:

```
SELECT 
      max(CASE 
          WHEN reference_field = "product_name" THEN value 
          END) AS product_name, 
      max(CASE 
          WHEN reference_field = "product_description" THEN value 
          END) AS product_description 
FROM my_table 
WHERE id=4`
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a join for this:

```
SELECT
  d1.value AS product_name,
  d2.value AS product_description
FROM
  product_description d1 JOIN product_description d2 ON 
      (d1.id = d2.id AND 
       d1.reference_field = 'product_name' AND 
       d2.reference_field = 'product_description')
WHERE
  d1.id = 4
```

This works best if you do not have many fields that you want to include in your query, since you have to add another Table to your query for every column that you want to add. But it has the advantage that you could display any number of products, not just one.